# connection to TraCI server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 104: Connection reset by peer -- in module

Tags: python, trace, omnet++, sumo, inet

While simulating VEINS i got the error mentioned above. I am also atteching the screenshot of the error below if any one have a solution please revert asap.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBPiz.png)

I have tried all the general solutions given on Internet

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you provide [mcve] as well as your environment (OS, versions of Veins, OMNeT++, etc.), your server's log and your log from OMNeT++? And one thing more: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).